# Install mysql-shell from apt repository

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, mysql-shell

I want to install and configure a high availability cluster for Mysql 8. To automate that, I want to use use apt repository (via ansible).
My servers are debian jessy (8) distribution.

I succesfully installed mysql server with commands :

```
> sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 5072E1F5
> echo "deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian jessie mysql-8.0" | \ sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql80.list
> sudo apt update
> sudo apt install mysql-server
```

It works fine. Now I want to install Mysql shell to manage a InnoDB cluster. It seems that it is available via apt repository as mentioned in this page :
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/
And installation is explained here :
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/installing-mysql-shell-linux-quick.html

But when I execute a install via reposiory, I get an error :

```
> sudo apt-get install mysql-shell
```

with the message :

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state
>   information... Done E: Unable to locate package mysql-shell

I have same error with server running on debian stretch (9).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding the APT repository like [gentiane's answer in this page](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/219376/255706), I downloaded the DEB file manually from the Internet following instruction from [MySQL page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/#apt-repo-setup):

(1) Download DEB file
   (2) `$ dpkg -i <DEB file>`
   and then
   (3) `$ apt-get install update` [instruction from here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-install-linux-quick.html)
   (4) `$ apt-get install mysql-server`
   (5) `$ apt-get install mysql-shell`

Runtime environment:
   Operation System: Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by adding the apt repository `mysql-tools` :
`deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ stretch mysql-tools`

It works for Debian 9 (stretch). Not tested for Debian 8 (jessie).